# onStartShouldSetPanResponder vs onMoveShouldSetPanResponder in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, gesture, gesture-recognition

I'm working with the PanResponder in React Native, and am considering the scenario in which I click an `Animated.View` and drag it. I have the following code:

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onPanResponderGrant: () => {
    this.animatedValue.setOffset({
      x: this._value.x,
      y: this._value.y,
    })
    this.animatedValue.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0})
  },
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
    null,
    {
      dx: this.animatedValue.x,
      dy: this.animatedValue.y
    }
  ])
})
```

My questions are:

1) If I click the `Animated.View` that the PanResponder is attached to, I know that `onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true` causes the `Animated.View` to become a responder to this gesture, but does `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true` cause it to 're-become' a responder on every subsequent increment of the drag gesture?

2) Does `onPanResponderGrant()` get called only when I first click the `Animated.View`, or does it also get called on every subsequent increment of the drag gesture?

3) In `onPanResponderMove`, are `dx` and `dy` the total accumulated distances from the beginning of the touch, or are they the small increments corresponding to the individual increment of the current drag gesture? ie. If I've dragged the `Animated.View` a total of `100px` in the `x` direction, would `dx` by `100px` or would it be something like `1px` for the current increment of the drag gesture?

If you can give me some insight on ANY of these, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No it will only become responder once. Usually you only need either one of them. For example if you only want a gesture to become active on dragging you would return no from onStartShouldSetPanResponder.
2. onPanResponderGrant() will only be called once for a given gesture. This is typically where you could update the state or UI to to notify the user that a gesture is active.
3. `dx` and `dy` are indeed accumulated x and y positions relative to the start of the gesture. So in your example it would be 100.